# Reading a full line of input

Tags: c++

I'm trying to store the input that user enters through console. so I need to include the "enter" and any white space.

But `cin` stops giving me input after the first space.

Is there a way to read whole lines until CTRL+Z is pressed, or something?

Comment: Possible duplicate. Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765462/how-to-cin-space-in-c

Comment: I didn't find this post while searching . if I did, I would post another one ^^ sorry , I'll try looking deeper next time

Answer (score 56, accepted):

> is there a way like readLines till CTRL+Z is pressed or something ??

Yes, precisely like this, using the free [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function (*not* the `istream` method of the same name!):

```
string line;

while (getline(cin, line)) {
    // do something with the line
}
```

This will read lines (including whitespace, but without ending newline) from the input until either the end of input is reached or `cin` signals an error.

Comment: @katia Only `getline` reads the whole line. If you input a string via `cin >> line` then it reads only until the first whitespace.

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() 
    string s;
    while( getline( cin, s ) ) {
       // do something with s
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For my program, I wrote the following bit of code that reads every single character of input until ctrl+x is pressed. Here's the code:

```
char a;
string b;
while (a != 24)
{
cin.get(a);
b=b+a;
}
cout << b;
```

For Ctrl+z, enter this:

```
char a;
string b;
while (a != 26)
{
cin.get(a);
b=b+a;
}
cout << b;
```

I can't confirm that the ctr+z solution works, as I'm on a UNIX machine, and ctrl+z kills the program. It may or may not work for windows, however; You'd have to see for yourself.

Comment: You are setting your self up for buffer overflows, this is not safe at all

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    std::cout << "enter your name: ";

    std::string name;

    std::getline(std::cin, name);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the getline function in c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char msg[100];
    cin.getline(msg,100);
    return 0;
}
```