# using getline for a c++ string to include spaces

Tags: c++, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading a full line of input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882872/reading-a-full-line-of-input)

I came across this snippet of code as a way to input a string (not a c string of char type) and have it read the whole line rather than stopping at the first space.  Can someone give me an actual example of this where I want to input the line until a newline character is hit?

```
istream& getline(istream& ins, string& strVar);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple google search of "getline sample": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ah895zy(v=vs.80).aspx

```
string s;
getline(cin, s);
```