# strtok() issue with space delimiter

Tags: c++

I am trying to break a string with space delimiter but it didn't work,where as with "," it works fine. Can anyone help me with this. Following is the piece of my code.

```
char x[150];
int a[150];
cin >> x;
int i = 0;
char * pch;

pch = strtok(x, " ");
while (pch != NULL)
{
    a[i] = atoi(pch);
    cout<< a[i]<<"\t";
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
    i++;
}
```

### input: 12 23 50

### output: 12

**output with comma separator:12  23  50**

Comment: Please don't use `strtok()`, it's not a safe function.

Comment: Debugging hint: Look at the initial value of `x` (before `strtok`).

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c

Comment: In C++ why are you using `strtok()` function? `C++ != C`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `cin >> x;` only gives you the input until the first space.

So even if you type `12 23 50` you'll only get `12`

The rest of the input remains in `cin`. So if you did `cin >> x` three times you would get `12` and `23` and `50`

To read the whole line use `std::getline` instead. See [Reading a full line of input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882872/reading-a-full-line-of-input)

But (as suggested in several comments) use of `strok` is not good. Also you should use `std::string` instead of the char-array.

For splitting a string, see the link provided by Dieter Lucking [Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c).