# String not working with #include <string> and using namespace std

Tags: c++

about the code below, string doesn't light up anymore and when I entered "John Smith", only "John" appears, string was working fine for me weeks ago until i tried calling strings function today which didn't work so i tested for a  simpler one.

```
#include <iostream>        
#include <string>      
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string name;          

   // Get the user's name
   cout << "Please enter your first name: "; 
   cin  >> name;

   // Print the greeting
    cout << "Hello, " << name << "." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[string doesn't light up like int](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dhvJ.png)

I might be asking at the wrong place but I cant' tell what's the problem, please help :(

Comment: *string doesn't light up like int* That because `int` is primitive and `string` is not, it is coming from a `include<>`

Comment: "using namespace std;" - bad habit. Don't do that.

Comment: Ohh thanks i'm new, glad it's just my problem :'D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a full line of input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882872/reading-a-full-line-of-input)

Answer (score 0):

With `std::string`'s, using `std::cin >> someString` will only read the first word off the buffer (it will stop at the first whitespace encountered).

Use `getline(std::cin, someString)` instead to read the entire line.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help :'D

Answer (score 0):

To get all the line, use  `getline(cin, name);`

instead of `cin >> name;`

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Comment: May I suggest https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline as a *better* reference? Cplusplus.com is (IMHO) a very *bad* reference site and not one you should use. Cppreference.com is *much* higher quality.

Answer (score -2):

std::cin gets only characters to first 'white' character, like space, tab or enter.

If you want to read whole line use e.g. getline()

```
string line;
cin.clear(); //to make sure we have no pending characters in input buffer

getline(cin, line);
```

Comment: While that's true, it's not the question. The question is about why the IDE doesn't display `string` the same way it does `int`.