# How to take space separated integers and chars as standard input in c++?

Tags: c++

I need to take `1 2 + 3 4 - *` as an input in c++, but couldn't
figure out, and even the size is not given about how many chars.
Need to take it as input ans store it in a string without spaces.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you tried so far? We can't help you if you don't show us your code.

Comment: @bb1950328 I tried like ```string s; char ch; while(cin >> ch) s += ch;```

Comment: @KlausMickhelson What were the results when you executed that code?  Just stating "couldn't figure out" does not indicate what the issue is.  If you stated "here is my code, but the string has extra spaces" or "the string when printed shows ...", etc. then that is a more focused question.

Comment: @KlausMickhelson [Could not duplicate](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/867fe14d50d474bf).  Please post a [mcve], or take the code you see at the link, and edit it so that you duplicate the problem you're seeing.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie actually mine was infinate looping

Answer (score 0):

Use the `getline` function ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882872/reading-a-full-line-of-input)) and the `remove_if` function ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83439/remove-spaces-from-stdstring-in-c)):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main(){
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
        line.erase(std::remove_if(line.begin(), line.end(), ::isspace));
        //do whatever you want with `line`, it has no spaces anymore
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though this may work, you don't need to call algorithm functions to simply get input without spaces.