# C++ music album print out the track title

Tags: c++

i a bit stuck on this question..

*header file*********

```
#include "Duration.h"

class Track
{
private:

    Duration trackTime;
    std::string trackTitle;

public:

    inline Duration getTrackTime() const;

    inline std::string getTrackTitle() const;

    Track(Duration d  = Duration(0,0,0),std::string trackTitle = "");

};

inline std::string Track::getTrackTitle() const
{
    return trackTitle;
}
```

*******cpp file..*******

```
using namespace std;

Track::Track(Duration trackTime , string trackTitle)
{
    this->trackTitle = trackTitle;
    this->trackTime  = trackTime;

}

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Track & t)
{
    Duration trackTime;
    string trackTitle;

    char c1;

    if (is >> trackTime >> c1 >>trackTitle)
    {
        if(c1 == '-')
        {
            t = Track(trackTime,trackTitle);
        }
        else
        {
            is.clear(ios_base::failbit);
        }
    }

    return is;
}
```

********main***********

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Track track;
    cin >> track;
    cout << track <<endl;


}
```

i just testing the ostream is what i expect.

but when i input the string like this. "0:03:30 - Hey Joe (Billy Roberts)"

it only print out "0:03:30 - Hey"

can anyone explain why the print out result like that.?
and how can i print out the whole track title.?

Comment: `operator>>(std::istream&, std::string&)` only reads in until it hits whitespace after characters are extracted. After you read in the duration, you can use `std::getline` to read until a newline instead.

Answer (score 2):

The `>>` operator inputs tokens, separated by whitespace (spaces/tabs/newlines). You are inputting only the first token of the title, so that's what you output.

Check out `getline`:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell cin to not skip white spaces when reading the track title - refer to [How to cin Space in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765462/how-to-cin-space-in-c)

Try the below

```
if (is >> trackTime >> c1 >>noskipws >>trackTitle)
{
    ...
```

Comment: thanks.. but its not working .. it print out like :0:00:00 -  and it should be 0:02:51 - Purple Haze