# Why does this call to isspace() never return true?

Tags: c++

Probably this is asked 100 times before, but i can't find or produce a solution.
Everything (as far as i have tested) is recognized, only pressing space is not working. I'm typing a space + hit enter, the cursor just moves to the next line and nothing happens. How can i make this work?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cout << "Press a key please:  " << endl;
    char key;
    cin >> key;

    if (isalpha(key))
        cout << key << " is a letter." << endl;
    else if (isdigit(key))
        cout << key << " is a number." << endl;
    else if (isspace(key))
        cout << key << " is a space." << endl;
    else if (ispunct(key))
        cout << key << " is a punctuation" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do some debugging. What is in `key` when you press space?

Comment: _"Probably this is asked 100 times before"_  yes a simple search would have shown [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2765462/1870232) !

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `32 ' '` . I have looked for the ANSII code for space and it is 32, but couldn't figure out how to use it.

Comment: That's not true. `cin >> key` does not put a space in `key`.

Comment: @P0W i have searched. Only reference i could find is how to identify spaces in a string with `isspace`. That is in the http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/isspace/

Comment: @Xbit `isspace` works fine. But `key` does not contain a space. Seriously what you really need to do is to learn some debugging. Almost any debugging would have led you to the realisation that a space was not being placed in `key`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you are right, it gave `32 ' '` with `cin.get(key)`. Usually i do use breakpoints and debug, but for some reason it wasn't working before.

Comment: Try doing this: cin >> noskipws >> key;

Comment: That is because the whitespace was eaten. The debugging showed you that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that `cin` uses whitespace as a separator (also tab, newline). Therefore, you have to read your input ignoring the separator:

```
cin >> noskipws >> x;
```

Alternatively use `get` for single characters:

```
cin.get(x);
```

Also have a look at [How to cin Space in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765462/how-to-cin-space-in-c)

Comment: This works. Almost had it, `cin.get(key) >> key;` but that didn't compute.

Comment: Because this makes no sense...

Comment: Odd that in the book they don't use `cin.get()`, also at least one example on the internet didn't use it. book says `cin >> key`.

Comment: Because this is the way to read in something in C++ and somewhere in the book they should mention, that it handles spaces and stuff as separator.

Comment: page 537: the overloaded operator `>>` automaticly skips whitespace and only returns one word(string) at the time.

Comment: Exactly, and ` ` *is* whitespace, isn't it? ;)

Answer (score 5):

When you use the formatted input functions (i.e., `operator>>()`) the input will skip leading whitespace by default. If you want to read a `char` which may be a space, you'll need to use the `std::noskipws` manipulator to disable this skipping:

```
if (std::cin >> std::noskipws >> c) {
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can use unformatted input functions, e.g., `get()` to read individual characters without changing the stream setup: the unformatted input functions don't skip leading whitespaces (which is often causing grief when changing between formatted input, e.g., for an `int`, and unformatted input, e.g., reading a line using `std::getline()`):

```
if (std::cin.get(c)) {
    // ...
}
```

Also, note that you can only pass positive values (and `EOF`) to any of the `is....()` functions but `char` is signed on many platforms. You need to turn your `char` into a suitable value first, using, e.g., one of

```
isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(c))
isspace(std::char_traits<char>::to_int_type(c))
```

Comment: You can also pass EOF to the `is*()` functions, but that doesn't detract from your point that the argument is supposed to be the `int` value of an `unsigned char` representation of the character (or EOF).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks! I have corrected the answer.

Comment: I would mention `istream::get()`. the most natural choice for general single-character input, imho. for the OP's specific case I would also recommend adding a `istream::ignore( -1, '\n' )`. well after checking that -1 would produce the requisite max value (pretty sure of that though).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I added a statement on `get()`. Whether anything needs to be ignored is a different topic (and don't see any reason it is). Of course, the spelling for the suitable constant is _not_ `-1` but `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()`.

Answer (score 3):

`cin` skips all whitespace (spaces, tabs, new lines, etc.) by default. You can either change its behavior, or use a slightly different mechanism. To change its behavior, use the manipulator noskipws, as follows:

```
char key;
cin >> noskipws >> key;
```

You can read more about this here '[How to cin Space in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765462/how-to-cin-space-in-c)'.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, always learning!

Answer (score 1):

### How to read a space character.

Replace this:

```
cin >> key;
```

which *skips whitespace* and *leaves text in the input buffer*, with this:

```
auto const max_streamsize = numeric_limits<streamsize>::max();

key = char( cin.get() );
cin.ignore( max_streamsize, '\n' );
```

which doesn't skip whitespace, and consumes all of the input line.

The problem with not consuming all of an input line, such as the terminating `'\n'` character, is that this remaining text will then be read by the next input operation, without first waiting for physical user input.

---

## How to use the C character classifier functions.

The C functions such as `isalpha` require a **non-negative** character code, or else the special value `EOF`, as argument.

With most C++ compilers the `char` is, however, signed by default. In general that means formal **Undefined Behavior** if it's passed directly to e.g. `isalpha`. For example, checking whether a `char` value 'ø' (Norwegian lowercase Ø) is alphabetical, by passing it straight to `isalpha`, is Undefined Behavior with most C++ compilers, and may crash in debug mode with Visual C++ and some other compilers.

A simple solution is to cast it to `unsigned char` (note: cannot pass `EOF` this way):

```
typedef unsigned char UChar;

... isalpha( UChar( ch ) ) ...
```

---

## Complete example, like the original code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>       // std::numeric_limits
#include <ctype.h>      // isalpha etc.
using namespace std;

auto main()
    -> int
{
    typedef unsigned char UChar;
    auto const max_streamsize = numeric_limits<streamsize>::max();

    for( ;; )
    {
        cout << "Type a character please (x to exit):  ";
        char const key = char( cin.get() );
        cin.ignore( max_streamsize, '\n' );

        if( key == 'x' ) { break; }

        if( isalpha( UChar( key ) ) )
            cout << key << " is a letter." << endl;
        else if( isdigit( UChar( key ) ) )
            cout << key << " is a number." << endl;
        else if( isspace( UChar( key ) ) )
            cout << key << " is a space." << endl;
        else if( ispunct( UChar( key ) ) )
            cout << key << " is a punctuation" << endl;
        else
            cout << key << " is some unknown kind of character" << endl;
    }
}
```