# how to replace every match of a charecter in the entire string?? in c++

Tags: c++

this my code when i give the input of `aeiou AEIOU` it only out puts `xxxxx` where did i go wrong??? i want to replace every vowel in the entire string but i only does it for the first word is my code wrong ??

```
#include<iostream>                                                                                                                                    
#include<string>                                                                                                                                      
#include<algorithm>                                                                                                                                   

using namespace std;                                                                                                                                  

class remove_vowels_class                                                                                                                             
{                                                                                                                                                     
 private:                                                                                                                                             

 public:                                                                                                                                              

    void remove_vowels_accept(string the_string)                                                                                                      
    {                                                                                                                                                   
      std::replace(the_string.begin(),the_string.end(),'a','x');                                                                                      
      std::replace(the_string.begin(),the_string.end(),'A','x');                                                                                      
      std::replace(the_string.begin(),the_string.end(),'e','x');                                                                                          
      std::replace(the_string.begin(),the_string.end(),'E','x');                                                                                      
      std::replace(the_string.begin(),the_string.end(),'i','x');                                                                                        
      std::replace(the_string.begin(),the_string.end(),'I','x');                                                                                      
      std::replace(the_string.begin(),the_string.end(),'o','x');                                                                                      
      std::replace(the_string.begin(),the_string.end(),'O','x');                                                                                         
      std::replace(the_string.begin(),the_string.end(),'u','x');                                                                                      
      std::replace(the_string.begin(),the_string.end(),'U','x');                                                                                      
      std::replace(the_string.begin(),the_string.end(),'~',' ');                                                                                      
      cout<<"the replaced string is :"<<the_string<<endl;                                                                                             

  }                                                                                                                                                   
};                                                                                                                                                    

int main()                                                                                                                                          
  {                                                                                                                                                   
remove_vowels_class maniobj;                                                                                                                      
string input_string;                                                                                                                              
cout<< "Enter a string to replace all vowels:"<<endl;                                                                                             
cin>>input_string;                                                                                                                                
std::replace(input_string.begin(),input_string.end(),' ','~');                                                                                    
maniobj.remove_vowels_accept(input_string);
```

Comment: What do you see if you print `input_string`?

Comment: Did you really need to put the Emacs mode line in the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cin>>input_string;` will extract text from the input until it reaches whitespace, so only the first word of your input will be put into input_string. Use `std::getline` in the string library to get a whole line.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::getline` instead of `cin>>input_string`

`cin>>input_sting` will only read input string till space.

```
std::getline( std::cin, input_string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like `scanf`, `cin` ignores whitespaces. Check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765462/how-to-cin-space-in-c). Try `gets` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/ in order to read the string.

EDIT: As @James Reed pointed out, `gets` is getting removed from the standard. Another answer has provided an alternative. I'm leaving the answer though for future reference.

Comment: `gets` is deprecated as of C++11. You shouldn't be using C-strings in C++ unless you have to, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [std::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/), here's a cleaner / simpler c++11 implementation.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string replace_vowels(const std::string & str) {
    static const char vowels[] = {'a', 'A', 'e', 'E', 'i', 'I', 'o', 'O', 'u', 'U'};
    std::string cp(str);
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        auto & ch = str[i];
        for(auto & v : vowels) {
            if(ch == v) {
                cp[i] = 'x';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return std::move(cp);
}

int main() {
    std::string input, output;
    std::cout << "Enter a string to replace all vowels : ";
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    output = replace_vowels(input);
    std::cout << "Input : " << input << " / Output : " << output << std::endl;
}
```