# C++ : Fastest way to read string from stdin

Tags: c++, input, getchar

We can use getchar_unlocked for fast reading of integers from stdin by manipulating the characters like:

```
int scan_d()
{
    int ip = getchar_unlocked(), ret = 0, flag = 1;

    for(; ip < '0' || ip > '9'; ip = getchar_unlocked())
    {
        if(ip == '-')
        {
            flag = -1;
            ip = getchar_unlocked();
            break;
        }
    }

    for(; ip >= '0'&& ip <= '9'; ip = getchar_unlocked())
        ret = ret * 10 + ip - '0';
    return flag * ret;
}
```

Is there a way to read strings from stdin in a fast manner using something like above? gets is faster than cin/scanf but at the same time possess critical handling of whitespaces. I thought of modifying the above code for strings but faced problems with whitespaces. Further, it seems reading every character of a string one by one will be slower.

By stdin I mean string is entered by the user (no file handling)

Comment: This smells of premature optimization.

Comment: `getchar_unlocked` also looks to be a non-standard function.

Comment: There's nothing like a `getchar_unlocked()` method in [tag:c++], what are you talking about?

Comment: You write modify to reading strings. I know from experience that string allocation interface is much slower than to read into a char buffer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `getchar_unlocked()` is in `stdio.h`

Comment: _'gets is faster than cin/scanf'_ `cin` which method??

Comment: getchar_unlocked is similar to getchar. It's not defined for windows OS

Comment: std::cin (console input)

Comment: @CPPCoder If it's not standard, it can't be available using c++ standard headers. But well, I see no reason why e.g. `std::istream::read()` implementation should be slower, than this. BTW: I meant which input method actually, `std::cin` is console input, I know.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If I read a string using gets, it's relatively faster than reading the string using scanf or std::cin.

Comment: @CPPCoder Again, which method of `std::istream` exactly? Did you mean the overloaded `std::operator>>(std::istream&,std::string)`? The latter might be slower, yes. To give us some insight, how you are measuring exactly would also be helpful.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Since he's referring to `getchar_unlocked()`, I'd guess that means that it's a version of `getchar` with no syncronization.  `std::cin` must sychronize across threads, and also by default synchronizes with cstdio.  When you add the per-character virtual call overhead, then it doesn't really matter which method of `std::cin` is used, they're all going to be slower than `getchar_unlocked`.  OTOH, this is pure premature optimization.

Comment: @MooingDuck You're right of course. _'OTOH, this is pure premature optimization'_ That's agreed for sure!! That's why I've been asking for the measurement methods.

Comment: _"Is there a way to read strings from stdin in a fast manner using something like above?"_ and due to _"By stdin I mean string is entered by the user (no file handling)"_, the answer is clear: take a faster user. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if my benchmarks are correct at all.. It is my first time testing speed really..

Anyway, here goes:

http://ideone.com/KruGD2

```
#include <cstdio>
#include<iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <chrono>

std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> hClock()
{
    return std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
}

std::uint32_t TimeDuration(std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> Time)
{
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(hClock() - Time).count();
}


void Benchmark(const char* Name, std::string &str, void(*func)(std::string &str))
{
    auto time = hClock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        func(str);
        str.clear();
    }
    std::cout<<Name<<" took: "<<TimeDuration(time) / 100<<" nano-seconds.\n";
}

void unlocked_bench(std::string &str)
{
    char c = '0';
    while((c = getchar_unlocked()) && (c != -1 && c != '\n' && c != '\r'))
    {
        str += c;
    }
}

void getchar_bench(std::string &str)
{
    char c = '0';
    while((c = getchar())  && (c != -1 && c != '\n' && c != '\r'))
    {
        str += c;
    }
}

void getline_bench(std::string &str)
{
    std::cin.getline(&str[0], str.size());
}

void scanf_bench(std::string &str)
{
    scanf("%[^\n]100s", &str[0]);
}

void fgets_bench(std::string &str)
{
    fgets(&str[0], str.size(), stdin);
}

void cinread_bench(std::string &str)
{
    std::cin.read(&str[0], str.size());
}

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    str.reserve(100);

    Benchmark("getchar_unlocked", str, unlocked_bench);
    Benchmark("getchar", str, getchar_bench);
    Benchmark("getline", str, getline_bench);
    Benchmark("scanf", str, scanf_bench);
    Benchmark("fgets", str, fgets_bench);
    Benchmark("cinread", str, cinread_bench);

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
Hello There
Hello There
Hello There
Hello There
Hello There
Hello There
```

Output:

```
getchar_unlocked took: 436 nano-seconds.
getchar took: 330 nano-seconds.
getline took: 619 nano-seconds.
scanf took: 522 nano-seconds.
fgets took: 44 nano-seconds.
cinread took: 67 nano-seconds.
```

Comment: I read the docs on fgets, you did fine there.  Also, I think ideone runs these on a separate server for accurate timings (it's part of SPOJ)  Therefore, I tried to fix your tests, but I'm having a problem with gets.  http://ideone.com/IbfD2E  It does clearly demonstrate that `getchar_unlocked` is fastest, and istreams slowest _by far_.

Comment: Ok how about now.. I changed the benchmark.. Is it fine now?

Comment: Added `cin.read`. @MooingDuck I used ideone because I don't have linux system to access `getchar_unlocked` atm. It doesn't compile in Mingw 4.8.1 on Windows. Doesn't work in MSVC 2013 either. Ideone was my only option.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: cin.read doesn't exhibit the same behavior as the others.  The function that does is cin.getline, which is already in my tests

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: You're doing a good job with this answer actually, except you're reading 500 lines and only providing 12.

Comment: @MooingDuck:  All I'm saying is that `cin.read` is another method to read from the standard input that bypasses formatting.  Although some compiler implementers have `cin` call the C language input functions.

Comment: @MooingDuck, I provided 500 but ideone deleted my post and I had to remake the link with less input. So in order for the link to stay valid, I had to trim it down to a certain amount.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Yes, but it reads a fixed number of bytes, which is very different from every other test here which read (up to a max) until they find a newline.  (A) the results wouldn't be comparable, and (B) it's likely to be closer to `cin.getline` than anything else.

Comment: I added a validator to verify that inputs were being read accurately, and used lambdas to avoid function pointer overhead: http://ideone.com/t7EJkn.  A warmup also made a big difference.  @CantChooseUsernames: the fact that `getchar` is slower than `getchar_unlocked` in your tests points out that there's a problem.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to read strings from stdin in a fast manner using something like above?

Certainly.  If you were clearer how you expected it to act, we could even provide code.

> gets is faster than cin/scanf but at the same time possess critical handling of whitespaces.

`cin` and `scanf` can do that as well: [How to cin Space in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765462/how-to-cin-space-in-c) and [How do you allow spaces to be entered using scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf)

> I thought of modifying the above code for strings but faced problems with whitespaces.

What problems?  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

> Further, it seems reading every character of a string one by one will be slower.

Slower than a block read? Sure.  But then, reading one character at a time is really the only way to tell where the end of the string is.  You could block read into a buffer and spin through that to find the end of the string, this is called buffering.  But `stdin` is already buffered, so buffering it again will make it *slower* not faster.  There isn't going to be a faster way of reading a space separated string than using `getchar_unlocked` one character at a time.