# Making a read function that allows spaces in the input (C++)

Tags: c++, input

"Write a class named `Person` that represents the name and address of a person. Use a `string` to hold each of these elements. Add operations to read and print `Person` objects to the code you wrote."

Note I haven't reached the section on access control yet.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

using std::string;

struct Person
    {
        string name_var, address_var;
    };

std::ostream &print(std::ostream&, const Person &);
std::istream &read(std::istream&, Person &);


std::istream &read(std::istream &is, Person &item)
    {
         is >> item.name_var >> item.address_var;
         return is;
    }

std::ostream &print(std::ostream &os, Person &item)
    {
         os << item.name_var << " " << item.address_var;
         return os;
    }
```

With this I can only read single worded names and addresses if I use `std::cin` as the first argument to `read`, which isn't very useful. Can you somehow use `getline`?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Comment: This should be what you are looking for: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/2765613/1587449](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2765613/1587449)

Comment: `Can you somehow use getline?` Yes. What more do you expect? Search the net for `c++ getline basic example`

Comment: If you read line by line you should also print/write line by line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
std::getline(is, item.name_var);
```

You can also specify a delimiter char as the third argument

Comment: Should I separate reading in names and addresses into two functions? I mean in the code I gave the user inputs two strings for a name and address, but your example would only read in a name.

Comment: @user110503 Nothing stops you from writing code after my std::getline example.
Instead of changing it to another function, why not define read and print as operator>> and operator<<?

Comment: I haven't done operator overloading yet, if that is what it is under.

Answer (score 0):

Look at one thing: you have used a space to separate name and address. Now, in order to know when the name is over, you need to use some other delimiter for name. Another delimiter means you need to enclose the name in e.g. double quote (") and then, while reading the name, get input until you get the second delimiter.

Comment: A newline is a perfectly fine delimiter that doesn't appear in names.