# C++ substring error

Tags: c++, string

So, I made a program that will let a user  enter a command, like `print message`
and it will show him the message he entered.
For example, if he types in: `print Hello`, the console's output will be `Hello`.

Now, here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string command;
start:
cout << ">>> ";
cin >> command;
if (command.substr(0,5) == "print")
{
    if (command.substr(6,command.end) != "")
    {
        cout << command.substr(6,command.end);
        goto start;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Usage: print text";
        goto start;
    }
}
}
```

The thing is I get an error:

> no matching function for call to 'std::basic_string::substr(int,
>     )'|

and I'm not sure if I specified the substring length correctly. I wanted the first if to check if the first five words were `print`.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing `command.end` with `command.length()`.

**Sidenote:** [It is good programming style to use the break, continue, and return statements instead of the goto statement whenever possible.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b34dt9cd.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Remarks)

Answer (score 2):

Your error is that you are providing `command.end` as an argument to the `substr` function which is not a valid parameter. It looks like you want to print the rest of the contents of `command`, in which case you can just call `command.substr(6)`.

Comment: Error after I write: "print Hello":
`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 6) > this->size() (which is 5)`

Comment: cin skips whitespace. Use the std::noskipws flag, cin.get, or std::getline:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765462/how-to-cin-space-in-c/2765613

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you forgot to write `#include <string>`. Also it would be better not to use `goto` operator and a lot of [magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad) (5, 6 in your code). For reading string (from standard input) that can contain spaces you should use [getline](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). In `substr` you omit the second argument if we want [to get all characters until the end of the string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/).

I have refactored your solution and have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string command;
  string prompt("print");
  cout << ">>> ";
  while(getline(cin, command) &&
        command.size() >= prompt.size() && 
        command.substr(0, prompt.size()) == prompt)
  {                 
     if (command.size() > prompt.size())
     {
       cout << command.substr(prompt.size() + 1) << endl;
     }
     else
     {
       cout << "Usage: print text" << endl;
     }
    cout << ">>> ";
  }
  return 0;
}
```